# Starting a executable from multiple threads through Process.Start()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, executable, process.start

I am using "7z.exe" to do some extra work in my application(c#).I have embedded "7z.exe" in the main executable of my application as a resource file. During execution of my application i extract "7z.exe" on a hard-disk and execute it through Process.Start().

I need to execute  "7z.exe" multiple times and from multiple threads.
Is it safe to access same "7z.exe" file from multiple threads? or should i extract separate "7z.exe" (to different location on hard-disk) for each process.Start()

PS:7z.exe belongs to Seven-zip software which is written in c/c++.

Comment: In addition to Jon's answer below, embedding executable files into your application as a resource and then *extracting* them later is hardly ever the correct approach. In particular, it's likely to drive a virus scanner nuts. Using a ZIP library designed for use with C# (like SharpZipLib) is a *much* better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to start multiple processes from the same executable file - assuming the process doesn't do anything itself to prevent that (which is feasible - you'd have to check for 7-zip). Can you definitely not do what you want using a zip library such as [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)?

Comment: In SharpZipLib, I still need to include "7z.dll".so whats the advantage in using SharpZipLib.I have to still extract 7z.dll.

Comment: @BitsnBytes: Does SharpZipLib use 7z.dll? I wasn't aware of that. But the advantage would be that it's easier to manage code within a single process than starting multiple processes.

Comment: considering  7z.exe allows simultaneous calls from multiple threads. Can i assume that 7z.exe will never be locked and will allow execution from further threads.

Comment: @BitsnBytes: You wouldn't be starting multiple *threads* - you're starting multiple *processes*. That's harder to manage, IMO. Yes, it will probably execute okay - but cleanup etc will be trickier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe to execute same exe file from different processes/threads.